# R# "cannot resolve view" when changing the default location for views + custom ViewEngine for ASP.net MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, resharper

We have a project in ASP.net MVC2 were we have our own ViewEngine that overrides were views locations are. Problem is that Resharper 5.1 is not picking up this, of course. Is there anyone who knows of a way to extend R# to pick this up?

I don't want to disable R# to not try to resolve view globally or local with the R# comment. I want to full tooling support.

Comment: Technically, you don't need a custom ViewEngine to specify where Views are stored. You can just set `ViewLocationFormats` on whatever View Engine you're currently using. R# will still choke, though.

Comment: Its not only for setting the locations - we do other stuff with the ViewEngine as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R# and Visual Studio don't have support for custom view locations. Imagine views stored in a database for example. You could still write to the R# team and ask to implement this feature in the next version.

Comment: I thought I did already, but now I can't find the request. Either way, this is probably the place to ask: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/resharper/resharper_community?view=discussions

Comment: I've done further crawling of the web and saw a couple of discussions talking about an architecture in R# 5.1 that allowed for a plugin to be written to resolve the views, but nothing specific. I'll post it on the R# forums. Thanks.